# merge in R to compare before and after

Tags: r, merge, compare

I somehow don't get the followig to work.

I have a data.frame with two columns, one column that contains strings and one index column. I replicate the data.frame. Names are "cleaning" and "control". I use a simple gsub function on cleaning which makes cells with a certain pattern NA or changes their contents. Now I want to know what has changed. I thought it might be easy to just merge them into a new data.frame with cleaning as column1 and control as column 2, using my index.
For example:

```
pat <- "AKGUN""
repl <- NA

cleaning$V1 <- gsub(pat, repl, cleaning$V1, perl=TRUE)
what.has.changed <- merge.data.frame (cleaning, control)
```

The problem is, I only get 2 variabbles in the new dataframe, and that does not help me at all.Anyone an idea what I do wrong? Ideally, I would only keep those rows that have seen a change. 
Many thanks,
Steffi

```
> dput(head(cleaning)) 
structure(list(V1 = c(NA, "ALEXANDER K, 2005, GLOBAL GOVERNANCE FI, P27", 
"BROMS B., 1953, SUOMI FINLAND, VVIII, P4", "ABDULLAH DS, 2003, NEW STRAITS TIM 0917, P10", 
"AGNEW J, 2010, POINT IS CHANGE IT, P214", "ABUNASR D, 2009, ASS PRESS       0329"
), index2 = 1:6), .Names = c("V1", "index2"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(head(control))
structure(list(V1 = c("AKGUN MENSUR, 2010, TESEV IST MARCH", 
"ALEXANDER K, 2005, GLOBAL GOVERNANCE FI, P27", "BROMS B., 1953, SUOMI FINLAND, VVIII, P4", 
"ABDULLAH DS, 2003, NEW STRAITS TIM 0917, P10", "AGNEW J, 2010, POINT IS CHANGE IT, P214", 
"ABUNASR D, 2009, ASS PRESS       0329"), index2 = 1:6), .Names = c("V1", 
"index2"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you share `dput(head(cleaning))` and `dput(head(control))`?

Comment: Sorry, still unclear to me. What is `V2`? Why is there no index column in `cleaning`? Can you also show rows of interest (that is, where `V1` starts with `"("`)?

Comment: If all you want is to look at the difference between the original `cleaning$V1` and the modified version, why don't you just add a column to cleaning? That is, instead of modifying `cleaning$V1` do something like this: `cleaning$V3 <- gsub(pat, repl, cleaning$V1, perl=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks Oriol, that worked- I added another if.else column and now I see what has changed. Lots to learn still!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working on the `control` data frame, I think the following might help using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

cleaning2 <- control %>% 
  mutate(V3 = gsub(pat, repl, V1, perl = TRUE))
```

Now if we wanted to only compare changes, we can make a few modifications:

```
cleaning2 <- control %>% 
  mutate(V1 = gsub(pat, repl, V1, perl = TRUE)) %>% 
  anti_join(control)
```

If you would rather see all similar columns, use `intersect()` rather than `anti_join()`